# Transposition Cipher errors python

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to write a function encr(k,m) where the message m is any string over the characters A...Za...z and where the key k is a permutation. When len(m) isn't a multiple of len(k), then I need to append Z's to m to make len(m) a multiple of len(k).

So far I've got

```
import math, pyperclip
def encr(k, m):
    ciphertext = [''] * k
    for col in range(len(k)):
        pointer = col

        while pointer < len(m):
            ciphertext[col] += m[pointer]
            pointer += 1
    return ''.join(ciphertext)
```

I keep getting an error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' on line 3, in `encr ciphertext = [''] * k`

Any help would be great

An example of input would be `encr([3, 2, 4, 1, 0], 'SineLaboreNihil')`

Comment: Is `k` and integer, or an list/tuple? You have `range(k)` but also `len(k)`.

Comment: Can you add a example of expected input and output?

Comment: k is actually suppose to be a list.
An example of input would be encr([3, 2, 4, 1, 0], 'SineLaboreNihil')

Comment: Add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You current error is that `k` is a string in your function, and you are attempting to add that to an integer - `pointer`. I think you meant to add 1 to `pointer`.

You are also attempting to take `range()` on that same string. `range(len(k))` is what you need to do.

Your new error can be corrected as follows -

```
ciphertext = [''] * len(k)
```

Comment: Even after changing the range to range(len(k)), it gets the error TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' on line 3, in encr ciphertext = [''] * k

Comment: Please update your question with the latest changes to your code.

Comment: I'm addressing your errors, but I'm not completely sure where you are going with this code...

Comment: That made it work, but it's not really encrypting the message at all?

Comment: So now you have to figure out what's wrong with the logic of your code. You can find plenty of examples of transposition ciphers and compare online.